# Xamarin forms UWP - Listview showing black background while loading viewcells

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp, custom-renderer

While loading Listview with data the black background is showing to load every single view cell. Does anybody know to change the color or remove that style?

I have tried to load the Listview from code-behind also. Is there any way to customize this?

Refer this screenshot [image]

The black background happens before the view cell loading.

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Pressed="Button_Pressed" Text="Back"/>
        <ListView x:Name="MyList" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HasUnevenRows="False">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid HeightRequest="60" BackgroundColor="Bisque">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Quantity}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

code-behind:

```
 public ObservableCollection<ListItemModel> listItems { get; }
    public ListViewPage2 ()
    {
        listItems = new ObservableCollection<ListItemModel>();

        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "First", Quantity = 1, Value = "10.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Secound", Quantity = 2, Value = "20.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Third", Quantity = 3, Value = "30.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Third", Quantity = 3, Value = "30.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Third", Quantity = 3, Value = "30.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Third", Quantity = 3, Value = "30.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Third", Quantity = 3, Value = "30.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Third", Quantity = 3, Value = "30.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Third", Quantity = 3, Value = "30.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Third", Quantity = 3, Value = "30.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Third", Quantity = 3, Value = "30.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Third", Quantity = 3, Value = "30.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Third", Quantity = 3, Value = "30.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Third", Quantity = 3, Value = "30.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Third", Quantity = 3, Value = "30.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Third", Quantity = 3, Value = "30.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Third", Quantity = 3, Value = "30.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Third", Quantity = 3, Value = "30.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Third", Quantity = 3, Value = "30.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Third", Quantity = 3, Value = "30.00" });
        listItems.Add(new ListItemModel { Name = "Third", Quantity = 3, Value = "30.00" });

        InitializeComponent();

        MyList.ItemsSource = listItems;
    }

    private void Button_Pressed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the associated XAML?

Comment: The question has been updated now @CorentinPane

Comment: Could you also show what you would expect to see? And also please show the xaml of your window (without un-needed stuff), at least the part that contains your ContentPage

Comment: I just don't want the black background while loading listview or change that color into transparent or white. Its look like flickering every time.

Comment: @Riyas,I try your code, but I don't see black background when loading data in ListView, What is the Xamarin.forms version?

Comment: Have you tried in UWP or what? I am using Xamarin.Forms 4.0 currently.

Comment: @Riyas Tested your code in UWP but could not reproduce the black background you mentioned. Used XF 4.1 and 4.2. How are you navigating to this page?

Comment: Nevermind I did lazy loading that solved the issue. Thanks for your suggestions.